# SQL inline if statement type question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to make an (MS)SQL query that returns something like this:

```
Col1 Col2                  Col3
---- --------------------- ------
AAA  18.92                 18.92
BBB  20.00                 40.00
AAA  30.84                 30.84
BBB  06.00                 12.00
AAA  30.84                 30.84
AAA  46.79                 46.79
AAA  86.40                 86.40
```

where Col3 is equal to Col2 when Col1 = AAA and Col3 is twice Col2 when Col1 = BBB.
Can someone point me in the rigth direction please?

Comment: I know this is old question, but now that we have SQL Server 2012 one can use `IIF` http://stackoverflow.com/a/23991354

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You didn't mention what kind of database you're using.  Here's something that will work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 
    CASE WHEN Col1='AAA' THEN Col2 WHEN Col1='BBB' THEN Col2*2 ELSE NULL END AS Col3
FROM ...
```

Comment: Ooh: hadn't thought of that interpretation of the question. I thought he was asking for a complex where-clause. It will be interesting to see which he uses.

Comment: I think he wants to filter the records.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` functions like thus, should the values be null:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Col1, 'AAA') AS Col1, 
       ISNULL(Col2, 0) AS Col2,
       CASE  WHEN ISNULL(Col1, 'AAA') = 'BBB' THEN ISNULL(Col2, 0) * 2 
             ELSE ISNULL(Col2) 
       END AS Col3
FROM   Tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your flavor of SQL.  Case/When works with SQL Server (and possibly others).

```
Select Col1, Col2, 
       Case When Col1 = 'AAA' Then Col2 Else Col2 * 2 End As Col3
From   YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from yourtable
where (Col3 = col2 AND Col1 = 'AAA') OR
    (Col3 = (2*Col2) AND Col1='BBB')
```

Comment: Ooh: hadn't thought of that interpretation of the question.  I thought he was asking for a computed column.  It will be interested to see which he uses.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the values are `null`, so they can be handled like this:

```
select Address1 + (case when Address2='' then '' else ', '+Address2 end) +              
    (case when Address3='' then '' else ', '+ Address3 end) as FullAddress from users
```