# SQL Server INLINE IF ELSE

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

In my table I got a column whose value is whether 0 or 1. If that column is 0 I output the value as 'no'; if 1 I should output as 'yes' for all rows. How can I do this only using SQL statement. Thanks

Answer (score 80, accepted):

SQL Server does not have an inline `if` statement, but it does have an inline [`case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) that can be use to accomplish the same.

Case has two forms, one is:

```
select 
 case MyFlag 
   when 1 then 'YES'
   when 0 then 'NO'
   else 'OOPS'
 end
from MyTable
```

where it's used just like a switch in C-like languages and the other is:

```
select 
 case 
   when MyFlag = 1 then 'YES'
   when MyFlag = 0 then 'NO'
   -- when some unrelated condition...
   else 'OOPS'
 end
from MyTable
```

where it senquentially evaluates a list of conditions and returns the first that is fulfiled.

P.S. The `end` part is mandatory, and I usually forget that.
It's also usual for a simple `case` stament to be completely inlined, like

```
select (case MyFlag when 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as MyFlagDesc
```

Answer (score 117):

I understand that this question (which shows up at the top of google results for "sql server inline if") is 2 years old, but with SQL Server 2012, the answers are somewhat outdated. It also appears to be a duplicate of [SQL inline if statement type question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287976/sql-inline-if-statement-type-question), but that question (being an even older one), doesn't have an up to date answer either.

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the [`IIF` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

Example:

```
SELECT IIF(someColumn = 1, 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Upvoted, I prefer IIF versus CASE for simple boolean conditions because it is more streamlined

Comment: The chosen answer works, but in case of using DISTINCT only your IIF will do the job. useful answer.

Answer (score 14):

Two possibilities:

```
(CASE WHEN condition1 THEN Value1 ELSE Value2 END)
```

or, the most complete solution:

```
(CASE value_to_check WHEN Value1 THEN Result1 [WHEN ... THEN ...] ELSE OtherResult END)
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE YourColumn
       WHEN 0 THEN 'no'
       WHEN 1 THEN 'yes'
       ELSE 'nothing'
    END
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Answer (score 7):

I mixed three IIF in one line, I have three variables and I want to know which one is greater than zero but I know the order of priority PersonHomePhoneID , PersonWorkPhoneID and PersonCellPhoneID

```
IIF(@PersonHomePhoneID > 0 , @PersonHomePhoneID, IIF(@PersonWorkPhoneID > 0 , @PersonWorkPhoneID, IIF(@PersonCellPhoneID > 0 , @PersonCellPhoneID, 0)))
```

The answer of question :

```
IIF(column = 1 , 'yes', IIF(column = 0, 'no', ''))
```

Comment: Is the compactness worth the loss of readability? I don't think it is.